# download failed because resources could not be found in some of android devices

Tags: android, android-resources, expansion

I'm working on one project with expansion file downloading, 
i have follow all the steps for uploading expansion file with apk, and it's working fine with some of android devices like android tablet 10.1 inch etc.. 
but, there is some problem with downloading expansion file for some devices like kobo arc, micromax funbook, it display error message like **download failed because resources could not be found**.  
internet also working properly. 
can anyone help for this issue ? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution with this problem. 
there was a little issue that, to download expansion file from google server **we must have to login with any google account** in device otherwise expansion file can't start downloading and always show message **download failed because resources could not be found** .